# submenu custom made jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pls check this link, http://ervaarelburg.nl/index1.html

I have issue in sub-menu, this is the JS for the sub-menu http://pastebin.com/MrJPDvct

So i want when i click on menu links, submenu opens, and by clicking anywhere else, sub-menu disappears. The problem is when i open it, it disappears automatically because of this code

```
$('html,body').click(function(event) {
     if(event.target.id == 'flip' || event.target.id == 'panel0' || event.target.id == 'panel1' || event.target.id == 'panel2' || event.target.id == 'panel3' || event.target.id == 'panel4' || event.target.id == 'panel5' || event.target.id == 'panel6'){
         $(".submenu").fadeIn("slow");
     }else{
         $(".submenu").fadeOut("slow");
     }
  });
```

similar like this one, http://ervaarelburg.nl/
but i want to modify the code for `index1.html` so can you please help in that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to use a more specified selector, then to check the event.target multiple times in an if/else clause. Try something like this:

```
    var isOpen = false;

// Clicking on the actual anchors shows in the submenu
$('#flip > ul li > a' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".submenu").fadeIn( "slow", function() { isOpen = true; } );
});

$( document ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    // If you clicked in the document, as long as you didn't click one of the
    // triggers, then close the menu.
    if( isOpen && ( $.inArray( e.target, $('#flip > ul > li > a' ) ) === -1 ) ) {
        $(".submenu").fadeOut("slow", function() { isOpen = false; } );
    }

});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grammar/qEfbT/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Hzhb9/1/)

Try this

Add `event.stopPropagation();` to each `.item` click

and to fadeout on click outside the element add this

```
$('html').click(function() {
for(var i=6;i<=10;i++){ 
       $("#panel"+i).fadeOut("slow"); 
    }
    for(var i=0;i<=4;i++){ 
       $("#panel"+i).fadeOut("slow"); 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you